# how to get the http header in asynchronous request mode using ASIHHTTP

Tags: iphone

I hope to display the download file size by reading http header.

I know there is way do this:

```
ASIHTTPRequest request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous]; NSString poweredBy = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"X-Powered-By"];
NSString *contentType = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Content-Type"];
```

but this is Synchronous mode, in Asynchronous mode it can be done as below:

```
(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request { unsigned long long contentLength = [request contentLength]; }
```

but 'requestFinished' is at the end of download.
Is there an event to get the http header info at the beginning of download?

Thank

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why you want that, but hopefully, you should be able to use:

```
// Called when a request starts, lets the delegate know via didStartSelector
- (void)requestStarted;
```

Comment: Thanks，this only worked fro the first request, it can tell me the correct file size, but if there is anyother request in multi thread later [request contentLength] always return 0.

Comment: Try using ASINetworkQueues instead? http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use
Section: "Tracking download progress for a set of requests"

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)requestDidReceiveResponseHeader:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
unsigned long long contentLength = [request contentLength]; 
NSLog(@"request Bytes = %llu", contentLength);
}
```